# Updating a Data Extension via Ampscript Web API

Tags: marketing-cloud

Attempting to update a column in a DE using Landing Page.  Code is throwing an error w/o any msg.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
%%[
VAR @retrieveRequest, @i, @currentSub, @j
VAR @properties, @Field1, @Field2, @numofProperties, @currentProp

/* Create and populate a RetrieveRequest */
SET @retrieveRequest = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@retrieveRequest, "ObjectType", "DataExtensionObject[Test_DE]")

AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","ET_Surrogate_ID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","Email_Address")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","First_Name")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","Last_Name")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","Mobile_Number")

/* Execute the Retrieve */
SET @emails = InvokeRetrieve(@retrieveRequest)

SET @emailCount = RowCount(@emails)
/* Iterate over the subscribers */

]%%
<br /><br />

%%[
FOR @i = 1 to @emailCount DO
SET @currentSub = Row(@emails, @i)
SET @properties = Field(@currentSub,"Properties")
Set @numofProperties = ROWCOUNT(@properties)

FOR @j = 1 to @numofProperties DO

SET @currentProp = Row(@properties, @j)
Set @Field1= FIELD(@currentProp ,"Name") 
Set @Field2= FIELD(@currentProp ,"Value") 

]%%

%%[if @j == @numofProperties then ]%% 
%%[
    if Substring(@Field2,0,2) == "1-" then
        if Substring(@Field2,3,3) == "121" then

        SET @sub_de = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
    SetObjectProperty(@sub_de,"CustomerKey", "Test_DE")

    SET @Attrib = CreateObject("APIProperty")
            SetObjectProperty(@Attrib,"Name","Mobile_Number_Locale")
            SetObjectProperty(@Attrib,"Value","CA")
            AddObjectArrayItem(@sub_de,"Properties", @Attrib)

    Set @update_sub =             InvokeUpdate(@sub_de,@update_sub_status,@update_sub_errorcode,@options)

IF (@update_sub == "Error") THEN

        RaiseError(@update_sub_status, 0, @ts_statusCode, @update_sub_errorcode)

ENDIF
]%%
    <b>%%=v(@Field1)=%%::</b> %%=v(@Field2)=%% <br/>
    %%=v(@update_sub)=%%
    %%=v(@update_sub_errorcode)=%%
    %%=v(@options)=%%
    %%=v(@ts_statusCode)=%%
%%[
        endif
    endif
]%%

%%[else]%%
<b>%%=v(@Field1)=%%:</b>%%=v(@Field2)=%%      
%%[endif]%%

%%[ 
NEXT @j
]%%
<br /><br />
%%[
NEXT @i
]%%
```

Comment: RaiseError will ALWAYS raise an error and needs to be put in an if block of some kind... is this the entirety of your code?

Comment: Tried that.  It is returning the same message above.  Please find the entire code above.

Comment: I would start with:

    SET \@properties = Field(\@currentSub,"Properties")

    Set \@numofProperties = ROWCOUNT(\@properties)


Field is going to return a field, which you cannot call ROWCOUNT on.  You would need to call something like BuildRowsetFromString or BuildRowSetFromXML to get something to call RowCount on.

Comment: It looks like the initial code was updating the DE properly however it was returning Error as the status (??) which is why it met the IF condition and attempted to raise an error.